# UI design pattern, or excellent example, for repeat delivery

Tags: website-design, design-patterns, e-commerce, purchase

Suppose I'm running a website that does repeat deliveries (e.g., ship you a Nuttella sandwhich and a tin of spam once a week). Are there any prevailing UI design patterns for displaying a customer's current repeat orders, and allowing them to easily customize them?

Alternatively, is there an online company that does repeat deliveries especially well?

This can't be a too uncommon need, but it's quite tricky to design without having a trade-off between these requirements:

flexible <-----> user friendly
quick to modify orders <------> adequate warning before purchase

Comment: Take a look at seamless. It's not the same model - but when I was using it heavily (last summer) I was impressed with it.

Comment: I've found Chipotle's online ordering easy and convienient. Not only can you simply repeat your order, you can very quickly modify it.

Comment: Where is this magical Nutella mailing paradise and who must I destroy to receive its favor!?

Comment: Silk road had a great customer base that seemed almost addicted to their regular product deliveries oh wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is an area where UX design patterns are going to be helpful, because this isn't a well defined enough user flow that a reasonable pattern can emerge.

That said, if I were designing this app and looking for helpful examples, I would assemble a taxonomy of something like the following sites:

- Banking and payment sites which offer recurring bill, rent and other payments.
- Sites which offer regular multi product deliveries, such as:

  - Farm fresh food
  - Trunk e-commerce
  - Wine clubs
- Sites which offer regular single product deliveries such as prescription drugs.
- Sites which are good at identifying and reminding users about recurring purchases (Amazon and Google Shopping Express)

I would assemble the workflow panels for each and then closely observe how they design for user experience, then figure out which approaches work for my app.

This actually doesn't take as long as it sounds... And it's going to be more instructive than just looking at 1 or 2 recommended examples. Good luck.